# Access underlying Map Area when it is covered with a SPAN or DIV

Tags: jquery, area

I have been working on a new map that works on Map Areas. On RollOver I am showing the province in a SPAN and this works well but obviously, when I show the SPAN with the province over it, the Map Area which then is the the trigger for the Off state is fired, causing it to bounce up and down which is not what I want.

I then resorted to switching from the Map Area to use the active SPAN so that when you RollOver the map area, it shows the SPAN with the province in it and when you RollOut of the SPAN, it is meant to hide the SPAN again.

The problem now is that the SPAN works on a larger square area unlike the Map Area co-ordinates which means that some of the maps which are smaller are difficult to target. Here's what I have currently.

**HTML**

```
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1727" alt="Map of South Africa" src="http://site/files/za-map-with-provinces.gif" usemap="#SouthAfrica" width="680" height="610" />
<map id="SouthAfrica" name="SouthAfrica">
  <area ID="Western-Cape" title="Western Cape Distributors" coords="59,421,62,422,66,407,79,408,84,393,92,400,101,408,101,420,106,438,108,455,120,465,124,475,123,493,136,481,151,470,149,489,157,498,169,505,181,494,201,479,219,475,230,465,233,452,240,443,249,453,266,459,281,453,295,448,304,455,315,455,312,466,295,477,279,481,280,492,282,497,269,502,264,513,256,526,274,527,289,530,297,535,286,543,289,549,296,552,288,555,282,563,263,558,248,557,231,564,224,572,205,573,192,577,173,579,156,587,147,597,132,591,120,582,108,572,98,564,89,562,85,568,87,553,87,541,80,529,76,517,68,512,64,505,65,498,74,498,76,497,81,494,81,489,80,478,80,468,80,462,80,452,77,442,73,438,69,435,66,432,63,427,59,422" shape="poly" href="/distributors/western-cape/" />
  <area ID="Eastern-Cape" title="Eastern Cape Distributors" coords="400,401,373,400,374,411,370,423,357,433,339,438,328,450,317,455,318,464,313,474,297,477,284,482,280,492,284,501,280,504,274,507,266,516,261,528,286,530,300,536,293,545,302,555,322,562,337,569,359,557,373,557,377,559,380,550,390,545,406,547,420,542,441,532,461,517,479,503,507,474,534,448,554,433,559,420,551,408,531,405,521,402,524,391,521,387,518,375,516,371,490,379,481,396,473,400,460,394,453,385,443,400,423,405,405,398" shape="poly" href="/distributors/eastern-cape/" />
  <area ID="KwaZulu-Natal" title="Kwa-Zulu Natal Distributors" coords="519,369,525,384,526,390,525,401,538,407,551,410,559,420,574,396,597,362,609,336,636,316,656,290,661,260,668,237,671,226,640,223,635,246,618,246,611,244,603,248,578,250,565,250,549,255,544,267,543,284,536,295,519,305,513,311,523,320,534,328,532,341,524,357,519,364" shape="poly" href="/distributors/kwazulu-natal/" />
  <area ID="Free-State" title="Freestate Distributors" coords="443,229,413,243,403,251,399,262,391,263,375,268,358,278,350,295,348,309,342,324,330,343,330,356,342,374,360,388,368,399,381,402,399,397,416,399,434,399,450,391,443,371,437,355,433,347,454,340,466,319,474,308,494,303,506,304,520,308,539,293,542,275,541,255,527,246,508,234,487,232,476,230,470,222,458,227" shape="poly" href="/distributors/freestate/" />
  <area ID="Mpumalanga" title="Mpumalanga Distributors" coords="631,182,633,166,636,144,635,125,632,110,630,95,619,99,601,102,604,115,599,125,588,121,580,136,569,138,560,156,549,161,519,160,517,148,508,140,494,147,504,152,500,164,509,169,515,176,508,186,498,191,507,199,507,206,495,218,488,226,496,232,519,240,533,249,543,256,566,250,597,250,606,243,594,228,587,218,588,204,596,188,606,173,621,176" shape="poly" href="/distributors/mpumalanga/" />
  <area ID="Limpopo" title="Limpopo Distributors" coords="410,125,411,123,420,111,429,108,432,97,438,80,448,68,464,62,473,52,483,44,490,31,509,31,511,25,524,18,548,15,560,17,567,24,587,22,603,21,611,26,614,42,617,59,620,73,627,88,628,95,607,98,593,99,598,106,602,115,596,122,584,122,574,135,562,149,543,158,527,159,524,149,521,138,510,137,504,142,496,151,487,152,484,144,476,140,462,141,451,148,442,140,435,127,428,133,417,134,411,131" shape="poly" href="/distributors/limpopo/" />
  <area ID="North-West" title="Northwest Distributors" coords="258,190,264,177,269,164,277,153,286,152,301,161,315,168,340,176,357,175,372,174,384,161,392,143,391,129,401,126,410,127,418,137,432,133,435,135,444,145,449,147,466,144,478,145,483,152,477,159,469,168,467,178,454,181,447,192,441,204,440,215,449,220,454,225,440,232,423,231,410,243,402,253,389,262,368,270,352,282,348,273,354,264,342,263,339,275,335,282,331,274,329,265,315,266,316,254,314,243,313,229,297,220,289,209,285,198,282,188,268,195,259,206,259,190" shape="poly" href="/distributors/north-west/" />
  <area ID="Gauteng" title="Gauteng Distributors" coords="473,222,482,226,487,229,492,219,496,215,506,212,509,204,502,201,499,194,499,190,509,186,516,180,511,171,506,171,501,164,501,157,498,153,488,156,484,159,473,172,471,179,463,184,457,186,450,194,449,206,445,213,450,217,459,226,475,222" shape="poly" href="/distributors/gauteng/" />
  <area ID="Northern-Cape" title="Northern Cape Distributors" coords="152,132,155,296,144,298,131,308,124,317,117,325,102,320,88,318,70,319,54,311,51,310,46,304,45,296,43,288,34,280,27,284,19,302,11,305,27,336,33,362,40,378,52,399,57,417,63,423,73,406,91,399,102,402,106,418,110,435,114,450,121,467,126,477,127,490,145,478,161,471,155,485,160,495,169,505,184,496,201,478,226,473,232,456,240,445,258,452,274,456,295,452,312,454,330,451,337,441,355,433,368,421,368,397,344,380,327,369,325,358,340,322,349,304,349,283,346,269,334,286,325,276,324,267,313,267,311,251,309,234,298,223,286,213,281,196,267,202,262,215,255,193,242,211,230,222,209,223,191,223,179,223,172,210,181,193,185,175,175,155,163,143,162,137" shape="poly" href="/distributors/northen-cape/" />
</map>

<div ID="MapWrapper">
    <a href="/distributors/north-west/"><span class="map-North-West"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/limpopo/"><span class="map-Limpopo"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/mpumalanga/"><span class="map-Mpumalanga"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/kwazulu-natal/"><span class="map-KwaZulu-Natal"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/gauteng/"><span class="map-Gauteng"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/freestate/"><span class="map-Free-State"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/eastern-cape/"><span class="map-Eastern-Cape"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/western-cape/"><span class="map-Western-Cape"></span></a>
    <a href="/distributors/northen-cape/"><span class="map-Northern-Cape"></span></a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
if(jQuery('#SouthAfrica')) {
    jQuery('#SouthAfrica area').each(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery(this).mouseover(function() {
            jQuery('.map-'+id).slideDown();
        });
    });
}

jQuery('#MapWrapper a span').each(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('class');

    jQuery(this).mouseout(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        //alert ("id = " + id);
        jQuery('.'+id).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Is there any way to target the Map Area for the Off State even though the province SPANS show when you mouse over Map Areas? Thanks, see the fiddle below.

**EDIT**
The only other way I can think of to do this is to add a Map Area to the individual province maps too but I am trying to avoid that as it's a lot of additional work and these maps will grow to other countries in the future.

Comment: It is not completely clear for me what you are trying to accomplish. Could you add a jsfiddle for this so we have a more visual example to test with? I've tried myself, but without pictures it's hard to imagine.

Comment: Thanks KoalaBear. Here's the Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sixfootjames/3u2hL/ . Essentially in this example you will see that to be able to use the Map Area for the Over and Out state of the mouse would be ideal but this cannot happen since the RollOver onto a Map Area triggers the SPAN to show, hence losing focus of the underlying Map Area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great. With the fiddle it's easy to see the problem with applying a red border on the spans :)

I used a duplicate of the current img with the same image (but it's better to replace with a single transparent pixel and remove opacity css) which uses the imagemap. Also the mouseover is not on the span anymore but on the same area which will also make the javascript code a lot easier to read. And those 2 images positioned on top of each other.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1727" alt="" src="http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-png-maps/za-map-with-provinces.gif" width="680" height="610" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1727" alt="" src="http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-png-maps/za-map-with-provinces.gif" usemap="#SouthAfrica" width="680" height="610" style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0;" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if(jQuery('#SouthAfrica')) {
    jQuery('#SouthAfrica area').each(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery(this).mouseover(function() {
            jQuery('.map-'+id).slideDown();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            jQuery('.map-'+id)stop().slideUp();
        });
    });
}
```

I've forked the fiddle with a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/6tRU3/3/

Adjust it to your likings. :)

**EDIT:**
I've added the additional jQuery .stop() on mouseout which stops that constant animation.

Comment: Wow! I'm miffed I didn't think of that option! Thanks Koala! Well done.

Comment: Great! A colleague proposed it :)

Sometimes the simplest answer is the best one.

Comment: Don't I know it..but finding that simplicity can be a needle in the proverbial stack sometimes :) Thanks mate.